# How to insert values of multiple select

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a list multiple select, this is the code :

```
<form method="post" action="">
      <select name=thematique[] multiple>
        <option value="1"> MIE </option>
        <option value="2">  Migration </option>
        <option value="3"> Réunification familiale </option>
      </select>
      <button type="submit" class="button" name="categoriser">Catégoriser</button>
    </form>
```

My problem is if I select MIE + Migration + Réunification familiale, so I have 3 lines in my data base for the same ID. 
I want to have one line which will insert all options of the select (0 1 2 or 3).

```
$id_struct=$_POST['id_struct'];
$thematique=$_POST['thematique']);
foreach($thematique as $item) {
                $string= $item.' ';
                echo $string;

    $bdd->exec("INSERT INTO categorisation SET id_thematique=$string
                    WHERE id_struct=$id_struct");
    }
```

PS : id_thematique is a foreign key.

Comment: don't insert comma separated values in db. so it is good that all have individual entry

Comment: Thks for your answer. Bu I'll have so much of values in db.

Answer (score 1):

1)
You need to add `VALUE` attribute in your select box .

2) Don't treated `INSERT query` AS  `UPDATE query`

Your select box

```
<select name=thematique[] multiple>
        <option value="MIE"> MIE </option>
        <option value="Migration"> Migration </option>
        <option value="Reunification_familiale"> Reunification familiale </option>
      </select>
```

Your php file for insert into three separate field

```
<?php 
foreach ($_POST['thematique'] as $thematique) 
{
 ///your insert code//
 $bdd->exec("INSERT INTO categorisation (`thematique`) VALUES ('".$thematique."'");
}?>
```

Comment: Thank you! I forgot to write VALUE attribute, I would like to write UPDATE after I wirite INSERT, it is a bad syntax, yes thanks :-)

Comment: I insert my informations but I want to have one line in the db

Comment: For one line you can use `echo implode(",",$_POST['thematique']);` and don't use `foreach` loop for this

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't work because my field is an integer :(

Comment: ohh then you need to change it to `varcare`

Comment: In fact I gave an example here, but in my code I use identifiers that are foreign keys that are to be applied to these values ​​varchar

Answer (score 1):

You can use array of you thematique as object array:

```
$thematiqueArray = array(0=>'MIE', 1=>'Migration', 2=>'Réunification familiale');
```

set your html options element like this:

```
<option value=0>MIE</option>
<option value=1>Migration</option>
<option value=2>Réunification familiale</option>
```

and on your POST catching similiar like this:

```
$thematique=$_POST['thematique']);
foreach($thematique as $key => $value) {
            $item = $thematiqueArray[$key];
            echo $item;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll try that

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to give base2 values to your select. Like 1,2,4,8 etc... then you can sum the selected values up, and know which are selected. But this only works if you don't need the values in other places.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did not understand very well. For example if I have 3 it would mean I selected 1 and 2 ( 1 + 2) ?

Comment: yes exactly, it's like the 777 in chmod (if you know that) 1 would mean you have selected only the field with value 1, 3 would mean you have selected the field with the value 1+2, 7 -> 4+2+1 ...

Comment: Okey, but how to do the difference between if I select 1+2 or 3 ?

Comment: You don't have a 3, that's the point, you only have numbers which are in 2^n. So you have 1,2,4,8,16,32 ... Taht's why i said it only works if you don't need the values for a calculation or something like that.