# I want to insert multi values from drop down list into a table in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am new to PHP and I have a drop down list with multi values for addresses and I want to insert the selected values to the table persons, in my code I got only the first value : state but I couldn't get the rest values.what I should do to make it work? her is my file(test3.php):

```html
<form action="test3.php" method="GET">
state :<select name="states">
<option value="state1">state1</option>
<option value="state2">state2</option>
<option value="state3">state3</option>
<option value="state4">state4</option>
</select><br>


   City :<select name="cities">
<option value="city1">city1</option>
<option value="city2">city2</option>
<option value="city3">city3</option>
<option value="city4">city4</option>
</select><br>


   zipcode :<select name="zipcodes">
<option value="zipcode1">zipcode1</option>
<option value="zipcode2">zipcode2</option>
<option value="zipcode3">zipcode3</option>
<option value="zipcode4">zipcode4</option>
</select><br>



   Name :<select name="names">
<option value="name1">name1</option>
<option value="name2">name2</option>
<option value="name3">name3</option>
<option value="name4">name4</option>
</select><br>


<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Insert">
</form>
```

```php
<?php
if(isset($_GET['states']))
{
    $name=$_GET['states'];
    $c=mysql_connect("localhost","user","");
    mysql_select_db("db");
    $ins=mysql_query("INSERT INTO `persons` 
                      (state)
                      VALUES ('$name')",$c);


}


?>
```

Comment: Can you add the structure of the table "persons"?

Comment: Please note the `mysql_` constructor is [**deprecated as of PHP 5.5**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), and is [**removed in PHP 7**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/remove_deprecated_functionality_in_php7#extmysql). Please consider switching to either [**MySQLi**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), ensuring that you also use [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to prevent [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) :)

Comment: What do you mean by _"couldn't get the rest values"_? They should be in `$_GET['states']`, `$_GET['cities']`, `$_GET['zipcodes']` and `$_GET['names']`. If you're wondering how to insert them all into the same row, I suggest you read the fine manual ~ https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html

Comment: What I *think* you're looking for is to have your `<select>` `name` attribute accept an array of options. For example, `<select name="cities[]">`, in addition to the `multiple` attribute. However, this question has been asked **numerous** times before (with [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32306345/how-to-insert-values-of-multiple-select) seeming to be the most similar).

Comment: my table has 5 col: Id , State , City, Zipcode & name

Comment: this code is working
     <?php
    if(isset($_GET['states']))
    {
        $state=$_GET['states'];$city=$_GET['cities'];$zipcode=$_GET['zipcodes'];$street=$_GET['streets'];
        $c=mysql_connect("localhost","hussamalmoussa","#Sstars1988");
        mysql_select_db("mere");
        $ins=mysql_query("INSERT INTO `persons` 
                          (state,city,zipcode,street)
                          VALUES ('$state','$city','$zipcode','$street')",$c);  
 }?>